# Code not working in production

Tags: apex

What is wrong with my code?

Description: The purpose of this code is to create multiple records based on two conditions

```
Custom Picklist: Value = Yes (condition set in process builder)
(Number Field) Contract Term (Number of years) =
```

So whatever is the value entered in the contract term custom field, those many child record would be created.

Parent Object: Opportunity Contract

Child Object: Annual Maintenance

**Error in Production**

This code is working fine in Developer Sandbox, after I installed in Production, this program is working as expected with the opportunity contract records which were previously created (before deploying this code)

However, this code does not work with opportunity contract records which are created after the deployment.

The error I am geting is “dereference a null object”

Where am I going wrong? Why this behaviour of working for existing records and not working with new records in Production?

**Finally i have recompiled all Apex Classes in Production, but the result is the same**

Any Help is highly appreciated!

Below is the code

```
public class OppConAMInvocableClass {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Insert Child Records for Opportunity Contracts' description='Inserts the child records based on number of contract years.')
  public static void insertChildRecords(List<Opportunity_Contract__c> parentList) {
      List<Annual_Maintenance__c> childrecords = new List<Annual_Maintenance__c>();       
      for(Opportunity_Contract__c parent : parentList) {
        Integer numberYears = Integer.valueOf(parent.Contract_Years__c);
        for(Integer i=1;i<numberYears;i++) {
        //Account acct = [SELECT Id FROM Account where Id = :e.WhatId];
        Integer j = i + 1;         
        Annual_Maintenance__c child = new Annual_Maintenance__c();


            Child.Anniversary_Date__c=Parent.Annual_Renewal_Date__c.addYears(i); 
            Child.Name=Parent.Name+'-'+Child.Anniversary_Date__c.year();
            Child.Number_of_sites__c=Parent.Number_of_Sites__c;
            Child.Opportunity_Department__c =Parent.Opportunity_Department__c;
            Child.Account__c=Parent.Account_Name__c;
            Child.Primary_Contact__c=Parent.Primary_Contact__c;
            Child.Annual_Maintenance_Start_Date__c=Parent.Contract_Start_Date__c;
            Child.Annual_Maintenance_End_Date__c=Parent.Contract_End_Date__c;
            Child.Opportunity_Name__c=Parent.Opportunity_Name__c;
          Child.Anniversary_Date__c=Parent.Annual_Renewal_Date__c;
            Child.Sales_Territory__c=Parent.Sales_Territory__c;
     Child.Annual_Maintenance_Amount__c=Parent.SMS_Maintenance_Amount__c;
        child.Opportunity_Contract__c=parent.Id;
        childrecords.add(child);
        }
      }   
    Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(childrecords);
    /*
    List<ID> itemIds = new List<ID>();
    for (Database.SaveResult result : results) {
      if (result.isSuccess()) {
        itemIds.add(result.getId());
      }
    }
    return itemIds;
    */
  }
}
```

Comment: can you see if Anniversary_Date__c is null?

Comment: Pranay, thanks let me check on this one, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting means there's a specific object in your code that is null at runtime, and you are trying to get a property from that object, for example

```
Contact c = null;
if(c.Email.contains('a') >>> This will thrown an error because c is null
```

The error should include the exact line of code where this is happening, so you should look at that line and see what variable/object you are working with, and figure out why it's null.

If you cannot reproduce this in a sandbox, maybe try a full sandbox. Alternatively, once you've identified what is null (but don't know why), you can add a few system.debug statements in your code that handles that object, so that you can check the debug logs and find out why it's null.

Comment: Unfortunately error email does not state on which line variable or object is showing null value. btw code is working perfectly fine in my sandbox...not sure where the problem is

Comment: If you have the developer console open when the error happens, you'll see the line of code.